# php url routing like a subfolders

Tags: php

for example, i have some of file like this

```
/index.php
/cat.php
/genre.php
/categories/hello.php
```

i want to make someone who access my site, must use the url routing what i want, like this

```
http://example.com/ ( for index.php )
http://example.com/cat/ ( for cat.php )
http://example.com/genre/ ( for genre.php )
http://example.com/categories/hello/ ( for categories/hello.php )
```

it's like deleting ".php" in the url, but added "/" as ".php", i have used the .htaccess script as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but this only removes ".php" without adding "/" ending

Comment: You can also make it directories with an index.php in it. Then your /cat/ thing also works without mod_rewrite. This method is probably also faster. Or you can rewrite everything that is not a file or directory to index.php and manage the routing from php.

Answer (score 0):

update your .htaccess like below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```